# Why is TOR relay receiving more than is sends?

Tags: tor

This morning, I started the relay.  I noticed a 7:1 ratio on recv:send.  I am wondering why is it getting more than sending? I would expect the opposite since the dir port is enabled.

Exiting is not permitted on this relay for my security policy.

Comment: How did you measure this ratio?

Comment: Vidalia's own reporting system.